# Do not include some characters in a regexp match

Tags: ruby, regex

In ruby, I have a string

```
# ---
# title: hello
# subtitle: hello again
# author: me
# ---
Content
```

from where I would like to get two captured groups:

- `title: hello\n subtitle: hello again\n author: me`
- `Content`

I have been trying with positive lookahead `(?=pat)` and positive lookbehind `(?<=pat)`, and with recursion `\g<name>`, but witout luck.

I know I could regexp + gsub, but, if possible, I would like to do it in a single step.

I think it's not possible but I would like to be sure before trying something else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you meaning like this: http://rubular.com/r/ingOm4AGAG

Comment: The string looks like (commented out) YAML. Maybe it's just a coincidence, but you could parse it via `YAML.load(s.gsub(/^#\s*/, ''))`

Comment: You cannot match non-adjoining texts with a single regex match operation. You must use some sort of a postprocess step here. Is that string part of a longer string? If not, you can use a single `gsub` to remove what you do not need: [`s = s.gsub(/^#( -+$[\r\n]*| )/, '').strip`](https://ideone.com/v3KxhG)

Comment: Ok, I tried to simplify the question but I see I did it badly. Now it is clear why it can't be done with `gsub`. @I'L'l answer is very close to what I need.

Comment: `input.gsub(/\n?# ---(\n|\Z)|# /, '')` ⇒ "title: hello\nsubtitle: hello again\nauthor: me"

Comment: You cannot do that in one step. Only in 2 steps.

Comment: @mudasobwa: You say so, then where is your answer? *I would like to get two captured groups* - it is impossible to obtain this kind of result with 1 regex match operation when the texts to be matched are not continuous.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh, sorry, I missed “**two** capturing groups,” possibly because it is a late edit.

Comment: I was afraid of that... @WiktorStribiżew if you write your comment as answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me, which one? I am not going to post an answer saying it is not possible.

Comment: Well, in my view the answer is that it is not possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you use a regex scan function with joining result?
For example:

```
string = "# ---
          # title: hello
          # subtitle: hello again
          # author: me
          # ---"  

string.scan(/# (.*): (.*)/).map{|e| e.join(': ')}.join('\n ')
# => title: hello\n subtitle: hello again\n author: me
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DmitryCat. But what I would like is a single regular expression match step. I updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @WaitingforDev..., what about this? string[6..-6].gsub('# ','') :3

Comment: It wouldn't give the result I want. I edited the question with more details.